# How to scale a signal in python on the x axis?

Tags: python, signal-processing

I need a function on python that can take an array and stretch it or compress it by a given rate. For example, lets say that I have an array a=[0,1,0,-1,0] and I want to stretch it by a factor of 2 then the result array would be b=[0,0.5,1,0.5,0,-0.5,-1,-0.5,0]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def rescale(arr, factor=2):
    n = len(arr)
    return np.interp(np.linspace(0, n, factor*n+1), np.arange(n), arr)
```